# Get the ascii value for a char, Ord equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, delphi

In delphi exist a function called [`Ord`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Ord) which Returns the ordinal value of an ordinal-type expression.

for example you can retrieve the Ascii value for a char in this way

Ord('A') return 65

Ord('a') return 97

in C++ which function i must use to get the ascii value for a Char.?

Comment: I'm a C++ programmer, I see Ord when I'm just reading a Delphi code. I wonder what it is and this question proves my assumption is right. Just feel it's a little overkilled.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A simple `int a = c;` where `c` is a `char` should work.

Comment: Won't work for ANSI codes above 127, unless some sort of compiler option is used. `int a = (unsigned char) c;` would be closer to Ord().

Comment: @Sergey, the word ANSI was never mentioned in the question, just ASCII. And ASCII is limited to 0..127. In any case, the ISO standard doesn't mandate whether `char` is signed or not.

Comment: @paxdiablo, but Ord() was mentioned. And Ord() does support characters above 127. And the cast should be used exactly because the standard doesn't guarantee char to be unsigned, while most implementation use signed by default. But it is better to use Unicode anyway.

Comment: Great answer. Good to know it's so simple, and that the default when casting does this,

Answer (score 11):

A char holds the ASCII value.

You can cast it to an integer if you prefer.

Comment: except that the C++ standard doesn't require ASCII

Answer (score 9):

Typecast it using `ascii = (int)character`.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
#include <ctype.h>

int LOrdValue = __toascii('a');
```

Comment: int LOrdValue = toascii('a'); will work too.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%d", c);
```

this would do...

if you need to use the ascii value for numerical operations, use

```
char c = 'a';
int i = (int)c;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do

```
char a ='A';
int b = a&0b11111111;
```

this should give 65